# Transform Ajax to stop using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have been using Ajax with jQuery to save pictures from canvas as follow:

HTML

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/take_pic.js"></script>
```

take_pic.js

```
$.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "pictureController.php",
      data: { canvasData }
       }).done(function(data){
          console.log("Success");
       }).fail(function(html){
          console.log("Fail");
});
```

pictureController.php

```
if(isset($_POST['canvasData']))
{
    $data = $_POST['canvasData'];
    saveData($data);
}

function saveData($data)
{
    //...
}
```

This was working perfectly yesterday but stopped working today.. It seems that pictureController.php is not called anymore! What is strange is that console.log logs `success`..

I would like to stop using jQuery and use Ajax only, how can I update my JavaScript to do so?

Thank you!

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: Ajax is a part of jquery!!. No JQuery, no AJAX

Comment: @BanujanBalendrakumar not a single one :/

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt I don't think that's true

Comment: @Wizzardzz: Have you tried anything at all?  When you look up examples of using AJAX in JavaScript, what do you find?  Where do you get stuck?  We can help with problems you encounter, but Stack Overflow is not a code conversion service.

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt: That's not true at all.  Not even close.

Comment: `$.ajax` .. here that dollar sign indicates `jQuery` but you can use `xmlhttprequest` in javascript without using jquery... But you said it worked yesterday, So I think the ajax not the issue

Comment: [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Comment: @David try using ajax without including jquery. If you do a HTTP request without ajax it is called XMLHttpRequest and not ajax.

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt: The `$.ajax()` *function* is specific to jQuery, the *technology* commonly known as "AJAX" (notice the difference in how the two are written and used) is general to all of JavaScript.  Please keep your terminology straight, this will help you better understand why you are incorrect.

Comment: `data:{canvasData:canvasData}` try this

Comment: @David Well I would like to fix my code before converting it to Ajax without jQuery. I'd liek to understand what's wrong and get people's opinion on what to do here...

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo Still not calling the .php :/

Comment: how can you say, not calling? how did you verify that? did you echo anything above the function? do you check it via developers tools etc?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo I have a header(Location) in my php file to know if it's called or not

Comment: @Wizzardzz: What does a location header have to do with it?  It sounds like it's time to use your browser's debugging tools.  You say you've already checked for errors on the browser console.  How about the network tab of the debugging tools?  Is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?  What are the details of that request/response?  Does it have the headers you expect?  The data you expect?  You've told us that the `success` callback is being invoked, so what is the actual indication of anything not working?

Comment: @David Thank you very much David! You made me discover the network tab which seems to be very powerful. It seems that the .php file is indeed called and that the ajax method is correct, I can't understand why nothing is happening tho. A picture should be saved from the canvas to a folder. I guess I need to focus on my debugging skills

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can do this with :

```
const req = new XMLHttpRequest();

req.onreadystatechange = function(event) {
    // XMLHttpRequest.DONE === 4
    if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if (this.status === 200) {
            console.log("Réponse reçue: %s", this.responseText);//ur response is here 
        } else {
            console.log("Status de la réponse: %d (%s)", this.status, this.statusText);
        }
    }
};

req.open('POST', 'http://www.exemple.com/pictureController.php', true);//url to get and method here
req.send({ canvasData });//data to send here
```

and for more documentation read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: Merci ! I'm going to try this